# No Release and Debug folders in Legacy Project

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying to modernize a legacy Delphi project (probably from Delphi 7). I'm using Delphi 10.3.3 now.

When I build the project, Delphi creates the .exe file in the project directory. But I want the .exe file to be created in Win32\Release or Win32\Debug folder. How can I change it?

Comment: Using the menu bar, go to **Project > Options** and then **Delphi Compiler**. Here, you can set the output directories for each build configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I can see .\$(Platform)\$(Config) is the magic word.

Comment: Might be worth creating a new project in modern delphi and comparing how the various settings differ